# How to use while loop in R to generate a matrix with specific number?

Tags: r, loops, while-loop

I have generate a matrix by using the following *for* loop. 
And now I am trying to generate a same matrix using *while* loop but don't know how to do so. 
Can anyone help with this? Thank you so much.

```
i<- 1
j<- 1
m1<- matrix(0, nrow=5, ncol=5)
for(i in 1:5) {
for(j in i:5) {
m1[i,j]<- (j-i)*2+1
}
}
m1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
i <- 1
j <- 1
m1 <- matrix(0, nrow = 5, ncol = 5)
while (i <= 5) {
    while (j <= 5) {
        m1[i, j] <- (j - i) * 2 + 1
        j <- j + 1
    }
    i <- i + 1
    j <- i
}
m1
```

Answer (score 2):

What about this:

```
> m       <- matrix(0, nrow=5, ncol=5)
> mu      <- upper.tri(m)
> m[mu]   <- apply(which(mu, arr.ind=TRUE), 1, function(x) (x[2] - x[1]) * 2 + 1)
> diag(m) <- 1
> m
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    3    5    7    9
[2,]    0    1    3    5    7
[3,]    0    0    1    3    5
[4,]    0    0    0    1    3
[5,]    0    0    0    0    1
```

---

**Edit:** sorry, just realized that you do not want to vectorize the task, but rewriting the code to use `while` instead of `for`. Although I have no idea why :)